# In storyboard in "View as" not shown ipads?

Tags: xcode

In storyboard in "View as" no iPads view. But in Launch storyboard iPads view present. I don't understand where something wrong and why I can't see iPads?

[image: No iPads, only iPhones]

Alse, I checked Deployment info, iPads turn on.
[image: iPads option turn on]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in the File inspector for the storyboard you disabled Trait Variations:

[image]

When you did that, a dialog appeared compelling you to choose one size class, and you chose iPhone:

[image]

It probably went by so fast that you didn't notice it! Or perhaps you did it long ago and you've forgotten...

Anyway, you should check both of the first two checkboxes (but not the third).

Comment: Many thanks, sorry for a long answer, my mac was in repair